# How to programmatically install a font

Tags: c#, winapi, compact-framework, fonts, windows-ce

I would like to install a specific font on my program load and use that font in rendering text of the program. How can I programmatically install a font from .NET CF on WinCE 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this helps better.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxcompact/thread/ee9a6947-0799-4a76-a7cd-c0bec4b7a2ab

Answer (score 2):

[This blog entry](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2007/06/22/EnumeratingAndAddingFontsInWindowsCE.aspx) shows how to enumerate and add Fonts in Windows CE using native code.  For managed code, this will work:

```
internal class FontHelper
{
    private delegate int EnumFontFamProc(IntPtr lpelf, IntPtr lpntm, uint FontType, IntPtr lParam);
    private List<string> m_fonts = new List<string>();

    public FontHelper()
    {
        RefreshFontList();
    }

    public void RefreshFontList()
    {
        m_fonts.Clear();

        var dc = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
        var d = new EnumFontFamProc(EnumFontCallback);
        var ptr = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(d);
        EnumFontFamilies(dc, null, ptr, IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    public string[] SupportedFonts
    {
        get { return m_fonts.ToArray(); }
    }

    private const int SIZEOF_LOGFONT = 92;
    private const int LOGFONT = 28;
    private const int LF_FACESIZE = 32;
    private const int LF_FULLFACESIZE = 64;

    [DllImport("coredll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);

    [DllImport("coredll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int EnumFontFamilies(IntPtr hdc, string lpszFamily, IntPtr lpEnumFontFamProc, IntPtr lParam);

    private int EnumFontCallback(IntPtr lpelf, IntPtr lpntm, uint FontType, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        var data = new byte[SIZEOF_LOGFONT + LF_FACESIZE + LF_FULLFACESIZE];

        Marshal.Copy(lpelf, data, 0, data.Length);
        var fontName = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, SIZEOF_LOGFONT, LF_FULLFACESIZE).TrimEnd('\0');
        Debug.WriteLine(fontName);
        m_fonts.Add(fontName);

        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy font *.ttf file to Windows\Fonts folder, it may requires restarting your device.

Comment: I cannot restart the device, it restores to original state when restart. So, I must install the font everytime my program launch. And plus, there's no Windows\Font folder. Any other way?