# Use a .ttf font in windows 6.5 C#

Tags: windows-mobile, fonts, truetype, windows-mobile-6.5

I try to use a .ttf file as my default application font but I haven't find how to load it... I've tried this :

```
customFont = new Font("MyProject.res.sony_sketch.ttf", 10F, FontStyle.Regular);
```

But when I use customFont, it displays the default one... Can anyone help me ? Thanks !

Comment: Take a look at this question, it may help on your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104949/how-to-programatically-install-a-font-in-windows-ce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to [that constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zet4c3fa%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) if the font family name, you need to first install the font, and then reference it by family name.

Comment: I will need to install the font on every mobile phone I wanna use with my application ? Is there no solution that will don't require any action for the end-user ?

Comment: @Laurent there is a [previous question that covers programatically installing fonts](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3104949/50447) and I'd suggest reading the answers there.